# Disable Daydream Controller

Tags: android, google-vr, daydream, google-vr-sdk

I am working on a VR app that does not use a controller, so the controller is never touched. There is a message that pops up after about 10 seconds that requires the Daydream button to be pressed to connect the controller. Is there a way to disable this message?

Comment: Please submit your code

Comment: I cannot submit any code since there is no place that the controller is referenced.